# How user can download a specific file?

Tags: plugins

I want to make a file download system in wordpress where user can download a specific file using filename or code.In user frontend user unable to see anything without a search box where they can enter file name or code to download the file.
How can I do This.Or which plugin should I use?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Please take a moment to review what types of questions are considered on-topic on this site - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic There may be plugins that do what you're looking for; you could search yourself or perhaps check a Facebook group where WP plugin recommendations are on topic. It might also be just about as easy to build your own solution if you're comfortable with PHP - you would just create a plugin with an admin screen where users could type in the filename or code and pull up the actual file from outside the web path.

Answer (score 0):

Add the files to your Media Library. The media library will give you a link to the files. Then make posts with the name of the file for title and a link to the media library created link to the path for your file in it. Now the default WP search widget will find the posts, user can click the link in the post and download the file. If you want control over who can download you can make the posts private for the ones you only want approved users to access. Anything more than that will require php and/or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try This plugin hope It's Work
https://wordpress.org/plugins/nmedia-user-file-uploader/

It's will give you a Wow feeling :)